# C socket client

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
            (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR connecting");

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the message: ");
        bzero(buffer, 256);
        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
        // n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

        bzero(buffer, 256);
        // n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
        n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

The code shown above works only at the first iteration. However, At second iteration it blocks at `recv()` or `read()`.

Could someone please explain the reason for this behaviour?

**Update:** here is the server code (not the one I'm using, but the same principles) and it works like the one I mentioned above:

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    memset((char*) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof (cli_addr);
    while (1) {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR on accept");
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
        n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Has the server actually sent you back some information to read?  It looks like you're using blocking io, so recv isn't going to return until it's read the data.

Comment: Don't use `bzero`, it's non-portable and the standard `memset` suffices.

Comment: @forsvarir yes, the server actially sent information back. If run this program first, in first iteration all ok, in second not. If run program second time, than at first iteration all ok too, bit in second not!

Comment: @larsmans, how can I do the same with memset?

Comment: memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));

Comment: What does the server do?

Comment: Are you working through this: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.  Because if you are, the default server implementation only echos the first message, then it closes down the socket.

Comment: Yes, i made server using the link above

Comment: What does the loop on the server side look like now?  Have you changed it?  (post the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop in the server code is at the wrong place. It should be changed to this:

```
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
        n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

In your code, you `accept()` a new connection in each iteration then `listen()` for a `read()` on it.  The client on the other hand does not establish a new connection, it performs a `write()` to the same socket.

Either your client needs to close the connection and reconnect each time, or the server needs to allow multiple `read()`/`write()` for the communication.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too! Thanks! It not works when I try, because there is another error :)

Comment: @azat: super... enjoy the next problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things with sockets I don't truly understand, but IF you do it like this, it *should* work. At least for me it does.

```
while(recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

If anyone knows why this work, please leave me a comment below :)

Comment: You haven't changed anything? :) recv returns 0, or <0 if nothings read, or there's an error condition... I believe the problem's server side... You change is unlikely to fix the problem.  In fact, it'll probably make it worse, depending if you're changing the existing while condition, since the server doesn't echo until after the message has been sent.

Comment: I wouldn't change the existing while condition. But I have used this before where calling read/recv once might freeze if it has not yet received anything on the socket before the function call, but by using this version it will run again and again until it does receive the answer. Of course the programmer should make sure it does not stay in this loop forever if it does not receive anything.

Comment: Unless you've set the socket up for non-blocking io, the first call to recv will block until it has received a chunk of data (it doesn't need to be in a while loop).  You might use a while loop if say you wanted to keep calling recv until an entire message (according to some defined protocol / or size had been read), before processing the message afterwards.